# rm: cannot remove `dir-name': Directory not empty

Tags: linux, command-line

I tried to use `rm -rf .vscode-server` to remove .vscode-server, and got `rm: cannot remove 'dir-name': Directory not empty`.

```
ls -al .vscode-server

# . .. bin

ls -al .vscode-server/bin
# . ..
```

I tried to figure out which process is using dir and found no result.

```
lsof .vscode-server/.
# empty result
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is something mounted in the directory? Maybe not, I get a "Device or resource busy" when testing that...

Comment: @Xen2050 I suppose there is nothing mounted in the directory. And I didn't get "Device or resource busy" either.

Comment: Try a `lsattr -R -a` on the directory? And what's in the .vs_wrong/bin directory? If it were some regular files you don't have permission to delete, I think you would get a different error... if something were immutable I think it might give a different error also, but might as well check. Another idea, could `rm` be aliased or changed? `which rm` or `type rm` show anything other than /usr/bin/rm ?

Comment: @Xen2050 `Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on .vs_wrong/.` occurs when try `lsattr -R -a`. Does this mean that I don't have rights to get access to these files/folders? So that I can not remove the folder? Also, I can not alias `rm` for I have no rights to do so.

Comment: Are you sure SE Linux is not enabled? Check the directory for SE Linux context for with `ls -laZ .vscode-server/bin`.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Hello, I tried `ls -laZ .vs_wrong/bin` and got `?` in the list as I updated the picture in the description of the problem.

Comment: I'm assuming the directory is not on an ext filesystem. Maybe the filesystem is related to the problem, what are the results of `df .vscode-server` (or it's bin and long 1a5... contents)  and then `mount` for whatever the "Mounted on" results are? Actually maybe `stat` on the directory & their contents could be helpful? `stat -c %m` tells the mountpoint also. PS. alias is a bash builtin command... are you even running bash, or what distribution, in a VM, or on bare metal, or from inside windows / windows subsystem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find and kill all the processes associated with VSCode:

```
ps -aux | grep vscode
```

Then you should be able to delete the folder with `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server`.

See
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340440/rm-cannot-remove-vscode-server-bin-xxxxxx-nfs000000000xxxxxxxxxxxx-device)
for more information.

Comment: Hello, I updated the question, and added a picture of my problem. You can see in the picture that there is no process using any file in the folder. And when I use `ps -aux | grep vscode`, I got the same result. I don't know why I cannot remove the folder. Or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Try `lsof` like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63340441/165358).

Comment: Hello, I tried `lsof` too, and sadly got not different but empty result. It seems that `lsof` is useful when there is `Device or resources busy`, but my situation is that `Directory not empty`:(.

Comment: Is there anything special about this directory? You could try to `sudo mv` it to `/tmp` and reboot.

Comment: I copied the directory from `.vscode-server` as a backup, so I think there is nothing  special about the directory. Sorry that I can not use `sudo` or `reboot` for I am not superuser. So what else can I do to make the directory disappear?

Comment: Without superuser permission the range is limited. Does `mv` to `/tmp` work? Try to re-login if you can't reboot.

Comment: I re-logined and tried to move the directory into `/tmp` and it doesn't work either. I got `mv: Directory not empty` too.

Comment: Sorry, without superuser permission I've run out of ideas. Perhaps you could ask for help from the administrator of the computer.